# How can I keep the datatable state when go to another page?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatables on my page. I am for example on page 5 in my pagination and then click on a row and this links me to another page. When I click on the back button of the browser I will be directed back to the previous page and in the datatable page 5 is selected.

I try to imitate this browser back button with jquery:

```
 <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

But now the datatable is refreshed and I am back at page 1. But I need the datatable to keep the page 5.

Comment: Note that traversing the history has nothing to do with jQuery, it's a Javascript issue. Also, the 'datatable' tag is for .Net. You need 'datatables' instead. As such I've retagged the question. Please take care when tagged future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stateSave` option here. As mentioned in the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave):

> When enabled aDataTables will store state information such as pagination position, display length, filtering and sorting. When the end user reloads the page the table's state will be altered to match what they had previously set up.

To enable state saving use:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  stateSave: true
});
```

Comment: ah, very interesting!